# Reference needed: Bernoulli numbers

Tags: reference-request, bernoulli-numbers

One of the nice identities about two-fold products of Bernoulli numbers is 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{(1-2^{1-k})(1-2^{k-n+1})}{(n-k)! k!} B_k B_{n-k} = \dfrac{1-n}{n!} B_n
$$
In some web resources it is credited for Gosper. But I could not find a proof of this identity.

Does anyone know the proof given by Gosper, and also alternative proofs if there are any?

Comment: I did not search for references but if I had to prove this family of identities, I would rewrite them all as the single functional identity $$(A(s)-2A(s/2))^2=A(s)-sA'(s)$$ where $$A(s)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k}{k!}s^k$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I checked it. The functional identity you wrote gives exactly the so called Gosper's identity. I had tried the functional identity $$A(s)^2 = (1-s) A(s) - s. A'(s)$$ which gave another identity for two fold products (Euler - Ramanujan identity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Bernoulli numbers can be defined through
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_n}{n!} z^n = \frac{z}{e^z-1} \tag{1}$$
we also have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_n(1-2^{1-n})}{n!} z^n = \frac{z}{e^z-1}-2\frac{z/2}{e^{z/2}-1}=-\frac{z}{2\sinh\frac{z}{2}} \tag{2}$$
and the given (convolution) identity can be read as
$$ \left(-\frac{z}{2\sinh\frac{z}{2}}\right)^2 = \frac{z}{e^z-1}-z\cdot\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{z}{e^z-1}\right)\tag{3} $$
that is straightforward to check.